# Send File to FrontEnd in feathers JS

Tags: feathersjs

I need to send an image to front end (avatar user) in the services 'users'. The file is stored in `./uploads/avatar`. My question is do I have to do an after HOOK or custom service when I use GET on service 'users'? Where do I need to write my res.status(200).sendFile(filepath)?

Comment: Can you perhaps post a part of the code so we can better answer your question? Have you checked out the multer package on npm?